# How to determine MPI rank/process number local to a socket/node

Tags: mpi, parallel-processing, openmpi

Say, I run a parallel program using MPI. Execution command

```
mpirun -n 8 -npernode 2 <prg>
```

launches 8 processes in total. That is 2 processes per node and 4 nodes in total. (OpenMPI 1.5). Where a node comprises 1 CPU (dual core) and network interconnect between nodes is InfiniBand.

Now, the rank number (or process number) can be determined with

```
int myrank;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);
```

This returns a number between 0 and 7.

But, How can I determine the node number (in this case a number between 0 and 3) and the process number within a node (number between 0 and 1)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on the MPI implementation - and there is no standard for this particular problem.

Open MPI has some environment variables that can help.  OMPI_COMM_WORLD_LOCAL_RANK will give you the local rank within a node - ie. this is the process number which you are looking for.  A call to getenv will therefore answer your problem - but **this is not portable to other MPI implementations**.

See [this](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/open-mpi/faq/?category=running#mpi-environmental-variables) for the (short) list of variables in OpenMPI.

I don't know of a corresponding "node number".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The pasted link is broken. I found this link that works https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=running#mpi-environmental-variables

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. Using `MPI_Comm_split_type` you can analyze the distribution over nodes without a problem. Maybe that didn't exist when this answer was written, but right now this answer is insufficient.

Answer (score 20):

I believe you can achieve that with MPI-3 in this manner:

```
MPI_Comm shmcomm;
MPI_Comm_split_type(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_COMM_TYPE_SHARED, 0,
                    MPI_INFO_NULL, &shmcomm);
int shmrank;
MPI_Comm_rank(shmcomm, &shmrank);
```

Comment: @aleixrocks That link describing MPI_Comm_split_type is failing. Here's an [updated one](https://cvw.cac.cornell.edu/mpiadvtopics/splitting), which just strips off ?Aspx...

Answer (score 3):

This exact problem is discussed on Markus Wittmann's Blog, [MPI Node-Local Rank determination](https://blogs.fau.de/wittmann/2013/02/mpi-node-local-rank-determination/).

There, three strategies are suggested:

1. *A naive, portable solution employs MPI_Get_processor_name or gethostname to create an unique identifier for the node and performs an MPI_Alltoall on it.* [...]
2. [Method 2] *relies on MPI_Comm_split, which provides an easy way to split a communicator into subgroups (sub-communicators).* [...]
3. *Shared memory can be utilized, if available.* [...]

For some working code (presumably LGPL licensed?), Wittmann links to [MpiNodeRank.cpp](http://git.rrze.uni-erlangen.de/gitweb/?p=apsm.git;a=blob;f=MpiNodeRank.cpp;hb=HEAD) from the [APSM library](http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.4280).

Comment: Strategy 2 is elegant and portable.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use

`int MPI_Get_processor_name( char *name, int *resultlen )`

to retreive node name, then use it as color in

`int MPI_Comm_split(MPI_Comm comm, int color, int key, MPI_Comm *newcomm)`

This is not as simple as `MPI_Comm_split_type`, however it offers a bit more freedom to split your comunicator the way you want.